# Laravel nodejs socket io

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io

for the life of me i can't get my pages to connect as client to the node js server serving socket io!

when the served page is a static one in the public_html file, all works great, but once i use views of laravel the client reverts to long polling that fails evetually.

i can't even get it to output the connection msg on the console.

**Server:**

```
var socket  = require( './public/node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./public/node_modules/express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('user connected');

  });
```

**client**

```
 <script src="{{ URL::asset('node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
    var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000');
```

**file order: shared hosting**

-Laravel Root(L5)

- app
- cache
- config
- public (same exact content as public_html)
- database
- Ressources
- ---> Views
- Server.js

-public_html

- images
- js
- css
- node_modules
- ---> express
- ---> socket.io

Comment: `do you have any console error`

Comment: yes , it displays (Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) with ajax polling

Comment: in which file this error belongs?

Comment: when you access the route in the browser, the script is i the  laravel view loaded

Comment: it means that your socket.io connection is not establish with node server

Comment: and check your socket.io lib properly attached in your laravel view?

Comment: thank you @uzaif the problem was the server ports were closed, the website is on shared hosting. thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On shared hosting ports are usually closed, i asked my hosting provider (awesome people) to open a port for the node server and they did, everythigs now is running smooth.

so bottom line: ports closed issue.